# Rails show record start from db with specific letters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to show only those inquiry processes where company name starts from specific letters. I thought I should use `start_with?` but in the code below I've an error

> NoMethodError (undefined method `start_with?'

```
def call
  InquiryProcess.all.includes(inquiry_field_responses: :inquiry_field).select do |process|
    process.inquiry_field_responses.select do |inquiry_field_responses|
      inquiry_field_responses.inquiry_field.name == 'company_name'
    end&.last&.value == start_with?('aaa')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
field = InquiryField.find_by!(name: 'company_name')
response_table = InquiryFieldResponse.arel_table
responses = field.inquiry_field_responses.where(response_table[:value].matches('aaa%'))
processes = InquiryProcess.where(id: responses.select(:inquiry_process_id))
```

First select the field that you want to check the values of. From there select all responses that belong to that specific field and start with `'aaa'`. Then select the processes using the responses.

---

The issue with your current code is that you'll do:

```
'some string' == start_with?('aaa')
```

Which should be:

```
'some string'.start_with?('aaa')
```

Or more specific to your case:

```
end.last&.value&.start_with?('aaa')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's much more easier.

Just use SQL for this:

```
InquiryProcess.where("company_name LIKE ?",  "aaa%")
```

This shows you all `inquiry_processes` that `company_name` starts with `aaa`

Comment: Unfortunately this is not that easy. To get company name I have to download last relation `&.last` and call `value`. If I change this code to `&.last&.value == 'aaa'` it will show me only InquiryProcess for companies with exactly that name so 'aaa' but I want to display all InquiryProcesses for companies starting their name with 'aaa'.